# Sampling an Image in C# with a TextureBrush repeatedly

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi, bmp, windows

So I'm creating a program in C# that takes an image and splits it up into tiles. I'm at the point where I want to take the big image and chop it up into difrent tiles and save each tile. The problem I'm having is it works for the first tile but all the other tiles are blank and I'm not sure why. Here is the code where I am doing the choping.

```
Graphics g;
Image tempTile;
TextureBrush textureBrush;
int currRow = 1;
int currCol = 1;
int currX = 0; //Used for splitting. Initialized to origin x.
int currY = 0; //Used for splitting. Initialized to origin y.

//Sample our new image
textureBrush = new TextureBrush(myChopImage);

while (currY < myChopImage.Height)
{
    while (currX < myChopImage.Width)
    {
        //Create a single tile
        tempTile = new Bitmap(myTileWidth, myTileHeight);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(tempTile);

        //Fill our single tile with a portion of the chop image
        g.FillRectangle(textureBrush, new Rectangle(currX, currY, myTileWidth, myTileHeight));

        tempTile.Save("tile_" + currCol + "_" + currRow + ".bmp");

        currCol++;
        currX += myTileWidth;

        g.Dispose();
   }

   //Reset the current column to start over on the next row.
   currCol = 1;
   currX = 0;

   currRow++;
   currY += myTileHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have blank tiles is this line:

`g.FillRectangle(textureBrush, new Rectangle(currX, currY, myTileWidth, myTileHeight));`

The coordinates `currX, currY` specify where to start drawing on the tile. After the first iteration of your loop, these values are outside the bounds of the tile.

A better method might be to try cropping the image by using `Bitmap.Clone`

```
while (currY < myChopImage.Height)
{
    while (currX < myChopImage.Width)
    {
        tempTile = crop(myChopImage, new Rectangle(currX, currY, myTileWidth, myTileHeight));
        tempTile.Save("tile_" + currCol + "_" + currRow + ".bmp");

        currCol++;
        currX += myTileWidth;
   }

   //Reset the current column to start over on the next row.
   currCol = 1;
   currX = 0;

   currRow++;
   currY += myTileHeight;
}
```

The crop method might look something like this:

```
private Bitmap crop(Bitmap bmp, Rectangle cropArea)
{
   Bitmap bmpCrop = bmp.Clone(cropArea, bmp.PixelFormat);
   return bmpCrop;
}
```

Comment: Yep that works perfectly, thank you very much for actually giving me a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the case that your:

```
    g.FillRectangle(textureBrush, new Rectangle(currX, currY, myTileWidth, myTileHeight));
```

call is trying to fill in coords outside its bounds?

for example, the tile is 10x10, first call:
        g.FillRectangle(textureBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10));

and on the second call, you are effeetively doing

```
    g.FillRectangle(textureBrush, new Rectangle(10, 0, 10, 10));
```

which is outside of tempTile's bounds?

that `fillRectangle` call should always be `0,0,myTileWidth,myTileHeight`, it is the *source location* in the `textureBrush` you want to change.  not sure exactly how you'd do that, maybe using a translate transform to translate it the opposite direction?

Comment: I dont beleve its going outside of the bounds. Sorry your answer dosent relly help me.

Comment: you don't believe?  as a test, try currx/2, curry/2 in that call, and see if it draws 1/4 of the tile in your saved image.